# get checkbox checked value in pug and node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, checkbox, pug

how to get the `checkbox` **value** if is **checked**, to redirected to this `(href="/player/edit/:id")` and `(href="/player/delete/: id")` , and receive the **value** of the `player id` for the `edit` and `delete` operations

It was not necessary to put the remaining code, such as `app.js` where it contains the `server`, the `routes` and the `request-handlers` and the connection with `MySQL`

this template `editPlayer.pug` is redirected to `(href="/player/edit/:id")` that receive `player id` and the doubt is how to get?

```
extends main

block content
    form(action="/editPlayer/:id", method="post")
      br
      label(for="name") Name:
      br
      input(id="name", name="name", type="text")
      br
      input(id="id",name="id",type="hidden", value="id")
      br
      button(type="reset") Reset
      button(type="submit") Save
```

this templates `player.pug` is to get the value of `checkbox` if is **checked** and redirect to `href` for button **edit** and **delete** `player` by `id`?

```
extends main

block content
   form(action="/player", method="get")
     table(
       thead
        tr
         th
          |ID
         th
          |Name
       tbody
         each player in players
           tr
            td
             input(type="checkbox", id=player.player_id, 
                     name=player.player_id, value=player.player_id)
            td
             |#{player.player_id}                                 
    div
      br
      a(href="/player/edit/:id")
          button(type="button") Edit
      a(href="/player/delete/:id")
          button(type="button") Delete
```

This is the example of the template  `player.pug` that shows the list of players and selects any one by `checkbox` and then click **edit** or **delete**
[image]

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen to send a form with GET parameters (i.e. `/player/edit/?id=5`) .  But you state you want to use path parameters. `"/player/edit/:id"`. I believe you have to use javascript here, because you cannot pass path-variables normally by using a form.

```
button(type="button" onClick='myEdit(' + player.player_id + ')') Edit
```

And then something like this:

```
<script>
    function myEdit(id){
        SomeAjaxCall( '/player/edit/' + id , successHandler);
    }
</script>
```

One alternative, of course, is to change the action-url of the form before submitting it.

```
<script>
    function myEdit(id){
        document.document.getElementById("myForm").action = "/player/edit/" + id;
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```